# What does "hace que" mean in this sentence?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Qué significa la frase *hace que* en la siguiente oración? Pienso que el 
escritor de esta oración quería decir que la profesora manda a sus estudiantes 
trabajar en grupos. Pero, me parece esta frase ser inusual.

*La profesora hace que los estudiantes trabajen en grupos de cuatro.*

---

What does the phrase *hace que* in the following sentence? I believe the writer
of this sentence meant that the teacher to ask her students to work in groups. 
But I am a little suspicious of the phrase *hace que*.

*La profesora hace que los estudiantes trabajen en grupos de cuatro.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general construct  would be `"hacer <algo>"` (transitive), which can mean "do something" (an action), "accomplish something" (a goal or result), "make something happen". Compare

1. La profesora hace *su trabajo*.
2. La profesora hace *que los alumnos trabajen*.
3. La profesora hace *trabajar a sus alumnos*.

In all cases, the words in italics work as a replacement for "algo", a direct object.`que` is needed here to make a verbal phrase  (los alumnos trabajan) work as an object.

> [que](http://www.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=que) :  Introduce una oración subordinada sustantiva con función
>   de sujeto o complemento directo. Quiero que estudies. Recuerda que
>   eres mortal. Es imposible que lo olvide.

2/3 are similar, and the difference (both in meaning and grammar) is subtle. Analogous examples: "Quiero que comas / Quiero comer"

Answer (score 5):

It means what you think it means (making the students to something), in English the phrase could be something along the lines of:

> The teacher makes the students work in groups of four.

And it is valid Spanish, it actually sounds quite natural to me...