# ¿Cómo usamos el subjunctivo con "cause and effect"?

Tags: subjuntivo

¿Es correcto decir "Gracias a ti, podamos empezar el trabajo"? Mi profesor me enseñó que necesitamos usar el subjuntivo con el *cause y effect,* pero no sé si esta frase es correcta.

I'm not a Spanish native speaker and have to learn it as a second language at school so excuse any of my mistakes.

Comment: There are many ways a "cause and effect" relationship can be expressed.  Some will need the subjunctive and some will not.  (Your example wouldn't.) See if this answer makes it clear which cases would take the subjunctive: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12070/9385.  If this doesn't clear things up, please edit your question (click below your question where you see "edit").

Comment: I think in Spanish a cause effect phrase has to be able to be the answer to a  "¿para que?" question ("for what?") 

I don't think that phrase is a cause effect  as the ending part in English is not "so we can finish the job"